# How to iterate through HTML nodes to find matches and get the next innerHTML from a node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form element `<select>` to select a person. As soon as the element has changed
the function `getPerson()` is executed and reads out the value of the selected entry.

```
<select id="cust_id" name="f_cust_id" onchange="getPerson(this)">
  <option value="51">Brad Pitt</option>
  <option value="123">Angelina Jolie</option>
  <option value="13">Jennifer Aniston</option>
</select>
```

The next step is: that I have a hidden text in the same page, where I want to find this value (example value 51).
I need to iterate trough this hiddenCustomer nodes.

Hidden HTML Text

```
<div id="hiddenCustomer" style="display:none;">
  <span>51</span><span>Brad;Pitt;Y1;Group1;bpitt@wwz.com;12345</span>
  <span>123</span><span>Angelina;Jolie;Y2;Group2;ajolie@wwz.com;12346</span>
  <span>13</span><span>Jennifer;Aniston;Y1;Group1;ja@wwz.com;12347</span>
</div>
```

finally if I have a match 51=51 I take the string from the next  element and "split" it to an array. It will be used to fill out some formular fields like: firstname, lastnamem, floor, group, email...

My question is: how to iterate best trough the hiddenCustomer nodes. Find the match and take the innerHTML value from
the next  element ( example : Brad;Pitt;Y1;Group1;bpitt@wwz.com;12345)

ps: I don't want to use JSON Objects.

Comment: Things would be easier if you nested your data SPANs into another container so they were child elements ...

Also, selectors that work in IDs are more performant ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getPerson(element){
    var elementsArray = [];
    $("#hiddenElement").each(function(){
         $(this).find("span").each(function(){            
             if($(this).text() == $(element).val()){
                 elementsArray = $(this).find("span").next().text().split(';');
             }
         });
    });
}
```

You end up with an array of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

[**DEMO**] `-->` http://fiddle.jshell.net/ykF6P/

```
function getPerson(element)
{
    var val = element.value;
    var $span = $('#hiddenCustomer span').filter(function(){
      return $(this).text() == val;
   }).next('span');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var value = 51;

var $span = $('#hiddenCustomer span:nth-child(odd)').filter(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).text(),10) == value;
}).next('span');

console.log($span.html());
```